# Javascript to change values in stylesheets

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking to find a way to change every instance of a color in stylesheets that get loaded into a site. I'm working with Prestashop and working with large theme style sheets and modules' stylesheets... so I'm looking to change font colors and background colors. Yes I can do a search and replace... but I'd like to have reusable code that I can use on multiple sites and multiple files and themes.

I've been checking out a bunch of articles on here and found some code that selects all the elements loaded and checks the ComputedStyle and if it equals one value, it changes it to a new value.

```
function colorToHex(color) {
    if (color.substr(0, 1) === '#') {
        return color;
    }
    var digits = /(.*?)rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(color);
    var red = parseInt(digits[2]);
    var green = parseInt(digits[3]);
    var blue = parseInt(digits[4]);
    var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
    return digits[1] + '#' + rgb.toString(16);
};

function changeColor(from, to) {
   var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
   var to = '#babaff';
   var from = '#f66685';

   for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
      var color = window.getComputedStyle(elements[i]).color;
      var hex = colorToHex(color);
      console.log('color=' ,color, elements[i]);
      if (hex == from) {
         elements[i].style.color=to;
         console.log('its a color match!', elements[i]);
      }
       var backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(elements[i]).background;
       console.log('bgcolor=' ,backgroundColor);
       if (backgroundColor.indexOf('rgba')<0) {
           var hex = colorToHex(backgroundColor);
           if (hex == from) {
              elements[i].style.backgroundColor=to;
           }
         }

   }
}
```

It's partially working, but doesn't seem to work on conditional values... like hover or active states. So ideally I'm just looking for something that just finds a string of text (the hex code) and changes it out... and it doesn't care what the element is (class, tag, id) and doesn't matter the rule (background, background-color, color, border, ect) because these themes are pre-built and not standardized.

Comment: Why not just use CSS to do this rather than the slow are laborious process of visiting every node in your document?

Comment: Definitely seems like something you'd want to do in SASS or using CSS variables. As @HereticMonkey said, doing this in JavaScript is very costly in terms of performance, it will also impose additional specificity limits in your CSS (if you need to overwrite an inline style your script is setting for any very specific use cases, you'd have to mark them as !important, which is bad practice if you can avoid it).

Comment: Well... I work for a company thats creating Prestashops in bulk for our customers. We have a base install with modules needed and themes. We'd like to keep the CSS from the themes and modules intact, so that if we need to roll out global fixes, we don't break sites. So I have been doing custom css styles... but its taking time to search the main theme for each instance and then copy the code over into a custom css and make all the changes... These them files and modules can be over 1000 lines of code and over 100 instances of one color.

Comment: And yes SASS or CSS variables would be ideal... but we'd have to rewrite all the themes css into SASS and its eventually something that we want to do, but we have production timetables to meet.

Hoping to find a quick solution to use until I can properly rewrite everything.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated:

"ideally I'm just looking for something that just finds a string of text (the hex code) and changes it out"

Thats basically what a search and replace does. (besides the hex stuff)

If you are looking at a problem like replacing a single color in your whole style, and it is very time consuming atm, then you are probably doing something wrong.

As @delinear mentions in his comment, you probably want to use a sass script.

Using some javascript to change all colors after the css has already loaded is performance heavy and not really the way to do it. 
I would really suggest a Search&Replace and to use sass variables afterwards.
(If you maybe want to change colors again)

there you can just do something like

```
$color: #ff00ff;

h1{
  background-color: $color;
}

h2{
  color: $color;
}

h3{
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, red, $color);
}

h2:hover{
  color: $color;
}
```

Comment: Yes... like I said we're using templates and themes in prestashop and modules... every little thing is specifically coded in by theme makers and module developers. Its the nature of the beast... its not good... thats why looking for something to get sites up and running so clients can start using them. We plan on overhauling the themes to add SASS.

Comment: @rekkid I'm afraid doing a Search&Replace in your case will be the quickest way to get the site up and running... In some IDE`s theres the possibility to S&R by directory or even in the full project. For IntelliJ/PhpStorm etc this is Ctrl+Shift+R hope this helps and you are getting it done quickly gl